# What is the procedure to submit OneLogin conector

Tags: saml, onelogin

We have made SAML enabled for our app and would like to integrate with OneLogin. Currently we tested it out with a "SAML Test Connector", and wanted to add our app to the OneLogin catalog. Were following the procedures in [Documentation](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/app-catalog), which guides to submit through [Request connector form](https://www.onelogin.com/product/request-connector) but the link is no longer available.

Wanted to know if there are any changes to the submission procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on implementing SAML!

I'm afraid you've caught OneLogin in the middle of switching help portal providers, so a few things appear to be broken.

For now, go to https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us and create a ticket. It should get routed to the right folks to help you out.

Comment: Will try to create a support ticket. Thanks for your response.